On RPi 4 GCC and CLANG use 16-bit loads
This is simplified from a larger example.
In the C source, I have:
uint32_t xx = oxdeadbeef ;

I compiled with gcc -O  or clang -O 
Looking at 'objdump -d a.out' on the RPi 4, I see
9ac:    5297dde8    mov w8, #0xbeef // #48879
9b0:    72bbd5a8    movk w8, #0xdead, lsl #16

This produces the correct result, but, these are 16-bit values.
How do I force gcc or clang to use 32-bits in this case?
mov w8, #0xdeadbeef
Or, do I want to?

Are you sure such an instruction (and not a pseudo instruction) actually exists on that architecture?

uint32_t xx = oxdeadbeef ; I am 100 % sure you do not have it.

ARM64 instructions are all 32 bits wide, unlike x86 where they are of variable length.  Since you need some bits for the opcode and register specifier, it follows that you can't encode every possible mov wn, #imm32 in a single instruction.  So instead the architecture designers limited it to 16 bits and provided movk to make it reasonably convenient to construct a larger value with multiple instructions.  We've definitely had other questions about this issue, but I can't find one that's really "canonical" to link as a dupe.  Maybe I'll write one at some point.

mov is not a real instruction.

This micro does not have the move immediate 32-bit value into the register, only 16 bits. 2 instructions are faster and shorter than storing the value in memory and loading it into the register from memory.
That's the reason why you have 2 instructions.
